# Recommendations for enabling basic logging for a small utility

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I sometimes write small utilities. There are times when I need to output what is happening to a text. Currently, I am using stringbuilder to hold my text and then right before my app is done processing, it writes the stringbuilder out to a text file.

I recently came across NLog and I like what I see. My only problem is that when I send my utilities out, currently I just need to send out a single .exe file. However, if I use NLog, I have to also include the config file (saw a post where you could theoretically create the config file and use it programmatically) and the .dll file.

I would prefer to have some form of logging that would still allow me to send my utilities out as a single .exe file.

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: Is your question "should I use NLog" or "how should I package applications that depend on NLog" - or something else entirely?

Comment: I understand how to use NLog. I was just stating that the way I am using it (as per the website examples), I have to deploy my .exe and nlog.dll. Currently I just send the .exe out rather than create an install package and that is how I would prefer to do it. If it is possible to create an .exe that would contain NLog.dll, that would be great. Else, I am looking for alternative to using stringbuilder / streamwriter (assuming there are better options), and NLog. Hope that is a little clearer. And thanks for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using default .Net tracing may be enough for your needs. Check out TextWriterTraceListener http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener.aspx which also includes sample of tracing to a file.

Debug.XXXX by default will be not available in Release buils, while Trace.XXXX are.

One can dynamically configure tracing levels if needed. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx and tracing overview at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5952w0c.aspx

Comment: If I am understanding Trace / Debug correctly, they are only supposed to be used when you are developing the application. Or am I still getting it wrong? I would like to be able to enable / disable logging and logging level via a menuitem.

Comment: Updated. Trace methods are normally available in Release builds.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I finally see the light :P

Answer (score 0):

Example of configuring NLog in code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4317263/161457

Merging multiple assemblies:

[ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630)

Alternately you could [create an installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t.aspx).