# Configuring log4net Programmatically for an AdoNetAppender

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, log4net

I have following code:

```
public class Log4NetSetup 
{
    public static void Setup()
    {

        #region log4net parameters

        AdoNetAppenderParameter logDate = new AdoNetAppenderParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@log_date",
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.DateTime,
            Layout = new RawTimeStampLayout()
        };

        AdoNetAppenderParameter thread = new AdoNetAppenderParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@thread",
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
            Size = 255,
            Layout = (IRawLayout)new PatternLayout("%thread")
        };

        AdoNetAppenderParameter logLevel = new AdoNetAppenderParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@log_level",
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
            Size = 50,
            Layout = (IRawLayout)new PatternLayout("%level")
        };

        AdoNetAppenderParameter logger = new AdoNetAppenderParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@logger",
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
            Size = 255,
            Layout = (IRawLayout)new PatternLayout("%logger")
        };

        AdoNetAppenderParameter message = new AdoNetAppenderParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@message",
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
            Size = 4000,
            Layout = (IRawLayout)new PatternLayout("%message")
        };

        AdoNetAppenderParameter exception = new AdoNetAppenderParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@exception",
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
            Size = 2000,
            Layout = (IRawLayout)new ExceptionLayout()
        };

        #endregion


        AdoNetAppender dotNet = new AdoNetAppender()
        {
            BufferSize = 1,
            CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
            ConnectionType = "REDACTED",
            ConnectionString = "REDACTED",
            CommandText = "REDACTED",
        };


        dotNet.AddParameter(logDate);
        dotNet.AddParameter(thread);
        dotNet.AddParameter(logLevel);
        dotNet.AddParameter(logger);
        dotNet.AddParameter(message);
        dotNet.AddParameter(exception);

        dotNet.ActivateOptions();


        Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();

        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(dotNet);
        hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Debug;
        hierarchy.Configured = true;

        //log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(dotNet);
        log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(hierarchy);

    }
}
```

Then I run that in Global.Asax on startup.

This was working fine in a XML file, but when moving it to code it no longer wants to work.

I was moving this into code and followed many other ways to do this on SO.
None of them seem to work in my situation.

[How to configure log4net programmatically from scratch (no config)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769983/how-to-configure-log4net-programmatically-from-scratch-no-config)

and

[Can you configure log4net in code instead of using a config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336917/can-you-configure-log4net-in-code-instead-of-using-a-config-file)

Comment: Do you receive any errors when running or does it simply not log?

Comment: It just does not log. With the xml config before it would log fine, so I mimicked the settings of that into the code. No dice though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there was an error, it was not causing a problem with the page though.
There was a invalid cast with the following code:

```
AdoNetAppenderParameter thread = new AdoNetAppenderParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@thread",
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
            Size = 255,
            Layout = (IRawLayout)new PatternLayout("%thread")
        };
```

Specifically:

```
Layout = (IRawLayout)new PatternLayout("%thread")
```

It needed to convert the type:

```
RawLayoutConverter rlc = new RawLayoutConverter();

AdoNetAppenderParameter thread = new AdoNetAppenderParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@thread",
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
            Size = 255,
            Layout = (IRawLayout)rlc.ConvertFrom(new PatternLayout("%thread"))
        };
```