# log4net: using PatternString in code, not in config file

Tags: c#, log4net

I would like to use the PatternString to specify a pattern in the filename for RollingFileAppender using log4net in C#. This can be easily done in the config file, and there are many examples of this online.  However, I would like to do the same in C# code.

This is how it is done in the config file:

```
 <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\Log\MyLogFile.[%processid].txt" />
```

My code below does everything about setting up the log4net without a config file.
Except the PatternString line above. How do I specify a PatternString for the RollingFileAppender **in code**?

My code looks like this:

```
public class Log4NetInitializer
{
    public static void Setup()
    {
        Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy) LogManager.GetRepository();

        PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
        patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date %-5level %logger [%ndc] %thread %newline%message%newline%exception";
        patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

        RollingFileAppender fileLogRoot = new RollingFileAppender();
        fileLogRoot.AppendToFile = true;
        fileLogRoot.File = @"C:\Log\MyLogFile.txt";
        fileLogRoot.Layout = patternLayout;
        fileLogRoot.MaxSizeRollBackups = 5;
        fileLogRoot.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        fileLogRoot.LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock();
        fileLogRoot.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(fileLogRoot);

        hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Info;
        hierarchy.Configured = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an equivalent (or I didn't manage to find it), you may anyway "cheat" and take care of the replacement yourself:

```
...
var pId = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
fileLogRoot.File = string.Format(@"C:\Log\MyLogFile.{0}.txt", pId);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The PatternString class in log4net.Util allows you to parse pattern strings as you would write them in the xml config file.

```
fileLogRoot.File = new PatternString(@"C:\Log\MyLogFile.[%processid].txt").Format();
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score -1):

This probably doesn't directly answer your question, but you can configure log4net (and NLog) via XML in code (as opposed to putting the XML in a config file).  I posted a question/answer about it some time back.

Here is a link:

[Configure log4net or NLog with XML from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317246/configure-log4net-or-nlog-with-xml-from-code)

My post is from the point of view of predefining/storing the XML somewhere (in my case our project was thinking about defining the XML configuration and storing it in a database), reading the XML (as a string) and setting it directly on the log4net or NLog configuration object.  We never actually got around to implementing anything using this approach, but in my limited testing, it did seem to work ok.